# UiCollectionView Spacing issue - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am having a spacing issue with my Collection.i Couldn't figure out why. I want the images from the Second row till the last low to be equally spaced. can someone help me to fix this. tnx.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return   singleUserModel.isevenItems(totalCount: CurrentUser.items.count) ? CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 0.4 , height: self.view.frame.height / 4) : CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height / 4)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width:  self.view.frame.width * 0.4, height: self.view.frame.height / 4)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return CurrentUser.items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UserDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! UserDetailCell
    configureCell(cell: cell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: UserDetailCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        cell.ItemImage.image = self.singleUserModel.loadImage(imageUrl: self.CurrentUser.items[indexPath.row])
        cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

View look Like this

[image]

Actual Output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set layout accordingly, Now your layout will be changed according to screen size So you need to calculate according to one screen size then it will work in other screen sizes:

Now, the layout will like this, In this 2 image will be shown in the width and if you want to set space from left and right side then set layout width accordingly.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 

collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            return   singleUserModel.isevenItems(totalCount: CurrentUser.items.count) ? CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 0.4 , height: self.view.frame.height / 4) : CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height / 4)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width:  (self.view.frame.width/2), height: self.view.frame.height / 4)
        }
    }
```

Remove minimins spacing for cell and lines and section inset will also Zero like below image:

[image]

Comment: You need to set Min spacing  0  for cells and lines and also section insets will 0

Comment: Bydeault min spacing is 0 so you need to set 0 then my code will work for you. I have updated mu answer please check